# "@" antes de método

Tags: php

*Estou realizando alguns testes com a função* `ldap_bind()` *e me deparei com algo que não conheço e não encontrei em pesquisa.*

---

Considerando a linha do script:

```
$bind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $auth_user.$domain, $auth_pass) or die("Erro em bind");
```

Se minha autenticação falhar, será impresso:

> Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in
>   C:\xxx\ldap.php on line 17
>   Erro em bind

Mas se eu usar um "@" antes do método:

```
$bind = @ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $auth_user.$domain, $auth_pass) or die("Erro em bind");
```

Ele não imprime o **warning**:

> Erro em bind

---

**Gostaria de saber a utilidade desse "@"**, se seria apenas para não imprimir retornos, etc!?

Comment: Po cara, eu não consigo achar nada no pesquisar do SO. 

Comment: não é culpa sua, a algum tempo nós reclamamos de algumas falhas no buscador que aparece no momento que vc esta redigindo a pergunta. Espero que melhorem isso um dia.